# Program breaks before it is supposed to in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, struct, while-loop

Not sure how I was supposed to formulate title!

I'm trying to write a program that asks the user for the name of a student. Then it stores that name in a struct and asks for a course name and the grade for that course. It does this until the course name is `stop`. Then it asks for another student until the name given is `stop`.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct student{

public:
    string name;
    string course;
    int grade;

}student_t;

int main() {


    while (student_t.name != "stop"){
        cout << "Please type the name of a student: " << endl;
        getline(cin, student_t.name);

        if (student_t.name.compare("stop")){
            break;
        }
        else{
            if (student_t.course.compare("stop")){
                break;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Please type a course name: " << endl;
                getline(cin, student_t.course);
                cout << "Please type the grade: " << endl;
                cin >> student_t.grade;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << student_t.name << " - " << student_t.course << " - " << student_t.grade << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, it exits no matter what name I type.

Any ideas?

Comment: `std::string::compare` returns 0 (inside an bool expression coerced to false) if they are equal, so by your logic, if you type anything other than "stop", the condition will be met and you will break.

Comment: Learn to use your debugger. You can step through this program line by line and inspect the value returned by every function. You would have noticed that `student_t.name.compare("stop")` returned some nonzero number even though the name is not `"stop"`. That should have been your clue to study the `compare` function more closely.

Comment: Thanks guys! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```cpp
if (student_t.name.compare("stop") == 0){
    break;
}
```